# hook_block_info_alter() is not working?

Tags: 7, blocks, installation-profiles

I am creating a custom Drupal profile and put down the following code.

```
function erc_360_min_hook_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $theme = 'erc_generic';
  $blocks['user']['login']['status'] = 1;
  $blocks['user']['login']['region'] = 'footer_first';
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is correct in terms of what Drupal is asking for, but after the installation, and going to look in my structure->blocks page, it does not update the blocks region at all.

Why isn't it working? The theme is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the code you show.

- If *erc_360_min* is the machine name of the profile, the correct name of the implementation of that hook is `erc_360_min_block_info_alter()`
- Setting `$theme` in that hook doesn't have any effect outside that function, since the parameter is not an object nor is it passed as reference; you rather use that parameter to check you are altering the blocks shown for a specific theme

See [`dashboard_block_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21dashboard%21dashboard.module/function/dashboard_block_info_alter/7.x) as guide to write your code.

```
function dashboard_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $admin_theme = variable_get('admin_theme');
  if (($admin_theme && $theme == $admin_theme) || (!$admin_theme && $theme == variable_get('theme_default', 'bartik'))) {
    foreach ($blocks as $module => &$module_blocks) {
      foreach ($module_blocks as $delta => &$block) {
        // Make administrative blocks that are not already in use elsewhere
        // available for the dashboard.
        if (empty($block['status']) && (empty($block['region']) || $block['region'] == BLOCK_REGION_NONE) && !empty($code_blocks[$module][$delta]['properties']['administrative'])) {
          $block['status'] = 1;
          $block['region'] = 'dashboard_inactive';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setting the region for the block is correct, but it's not correct what I previously described.